# Javascript: palindrome function?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, palindrome

I have working code for a simple word flipper:

```
var strFlip = function(str) {
    return str.split(" ").map(function(word) {
        return word.split("").reverse().join("");
    }).join(" ");    
};

console.log(strFlip("This is designed to swap the letter order of each word in the string"));

// "sihT si dengised ot paws eht rettel redro fo hcae drow ni eht gnirts"
```

I want to add an if/else to allow this code to now identify if each word in a string is a palindrome (spelled the same forward and backward ex: hannah).

So I tried continuing the .map() logic with:

```
var strFlip = function(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(function(word) {
    return word.split("").reverse().join("");
      }).join(" ").toLowerCase().map(function(test) {
    if (test.split(" ") === word){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
   );
};

console.log(strFlip("Hannah loves her racecar"));
```

BUT.... unsurprisingly, it returns an error essentially stating that the long linked collection of functions before the `if` section is not itself a function:

`TypeError: str.split(...).map(...).join(...).toLowerCase(...).map is not a function`

I was also getting lost trying to match all of the curly braces, but I think I got them all.

So, is it possible to add the if/else within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.join(" ").toLowerCase()` returns a string, not an array. The error is stating that `'some string'.map` is not a function because it's `undefined`.

If what you want is an array that indicates whether a word at an index is a palindrome then...

```js
var sentence = 'Eve drives a racecar',
        words = sentence.split(" ").map(function(word) {
                    var isPalindrome = word.length > 1 && (word.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join(""));
                    return { text: word, isPalindrome: isPalindrome };
                });
    alert(JSON.stringify(words));
```

Comment: Note that you should probably remove punctuation from your sentence first. "racecar." with a period would not be a palindrome.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. My only confusion is how to alter this into a function for reuse, instead of entering the text inside the `sentence = ''`. So that I could simply use `console.log(sentence('Eve drives a racecar'))` or whatever example test.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Just create a function that takes a string and runs the above code on it.

Comment: I suppose I am just confused by a  few parts of the code. How/why is `words` not defined first by `var`?

Comment: It is, note the comma on the line before.